# Как сделать наложение линий поверх всех окон

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть активный процесс, в котором необходимо кликать, и есть tkinter с Canvas.
Я хочу отрисовать линию от центра внизу экрана до ног какого либо существа.

```
def TargetLineESP():
    while True:
        if ...(Проверка активного окна):
            for i in range(64):
                if pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + i * 0x10):
                    entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + i * 0x10)# Получение существа
                    entitypos_x = pm.read_float(entity + m_vecOrigin)#X координата существа
                    entitypos_y = pm.read_float(entity + m_vecOrigin + 4)# Y Координата существа
                    root = Tk()
                    root.overrideredirect(False)
                    root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
                    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
                    root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "gray")
                    root.attributes('-alpha', 0.1)
                    c = Canvas(root, width=1920, height=1080)
                    c.pack()
                    c.create_line(960, 1080, 3, 5)
                    root.mainloop()
```

Я пытаюсь отрисовать линии, используя canvas. Если указать ('-alpha', 1), то окно ткинтера перекрывает активное окно, если указать ('-alpha', 0), то не будет видно никаких линий.
Я думаю, что можно наложить картинку ткинтера на активное окно, но мне кажется, что активное окно перестанет быть активным.

Comment: А куда надо отрисовать линию? Что от центра внизу экрана, это понятно, дальше как.